# Laravel LengthAwarePaginator returned data are not in single obejct

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, collections, backend

So i have made a custom pagination in laravel 5.4 using

```
Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator;
\Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;
```

it returns the correct data and format during first request, but the 2nd request and others are not formatted same way as the first one.

So my question is how do I make the data to always return in a single object like the first request?

Below is my code on how I did my custom paginator and the console log.

```
$data = collect($playerMatchArr);

$result = new LengthAwarePaginator(
    $data->forPage($page, 3), 
    $data->count(), 
    $limit, 
    $page
);
```

[image: console result]

Comment: Is your first and second request using the same code that you mentioned above?

Comment: @DharmaSaputra yes same code. Only the page parameter value is changing every request like leaderboard?page=1&limit=3

Comment: Do you `return $result` directly on your controller method? Because `LengthAwarePaginator` json output should be like this: http://imgur.com/a/GeAJk. I think you are returning something else on your controller.

Comment: yes I did return $result on my method

Comment: Your json output looks very different. Because if  `LengthAwarePaginator` returned in controller, it will contains: `current_page`, `from`, etc, and it will wrap the data on `data` field.

Comment: I know and that's what I don't understand.

Comment: @PenAndPapers did you managed to fixed this issue ?

Answer (score 2):

It is laravel json response which is doing this. I also spent couple of hours on it

finally managed to convert the response on the front end by receiving the response as

```
Object.values(response.data.data)
```

And finally i got the results

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I found out that it's because **keys** of page 2 or more doesn’t start from **0 ( zero )** now can simply generate new collection or array which keys start from **0 ( zero )**.

There is two ways for this: 
Way one

```
array_values($data->forPage($page, 3));
```

Way two

```
collect([...$data->forPage($page, 3)]);
```

Overall you can fix it by refactor your code to this:

```
$data = collect($playerMatchArr);

$result = new LengthAwarePaginator(
    array_values($data->forPage($page, 3)), 
    $data->count(), 
    $limit, 
    $page
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = collect($playerMatchArr);
$dataPerPage = $data->forPage($page, 3);
$dataPerPage = array_values($dataPerPage->toArray());
$dataPerPage = Collection::make($dataPerPage);
$result = new LengthAwarePaginator(
    $dataPerPage,
    $data->count(),
    $limit,
    $page
);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post code-only answers but add a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works and what makes it different from the other answers given. You can find out more at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page.